# Wrap header text via CSS in Webix datatable

Tags: css, user-interface, datatable, header, webix

I'm trying to apply a CSS to wrap the text in the Webix datatable header. Using this:

```
.wraphead{   
  line-height: 20px !important;         
  top:15px !important;
}
```

But the `top` property doesn't apply to the header - how can I overcome this issue?

The [snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/701a0c5e) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use attribute: position. 
Position: fixed || absolute || relative || static
For apply to, top, left, bottom and right.